# Forward declaration and typeid

Tags: c++, gcc, declaration, forward-declaration, typeid

I would like to check the type of a superclass `A` against the type of a subclass `B` (with a method inside the superclass `A`, so that `B` will inherit it).

Here's what I thought did the trick (that is, the use of forward declaration):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A {
  public:
    int i_;
    void Check () {
      if (typeid (*this) == typeid (B))
        cout << "True: Same type as B." << endl;
      else
        cout << "False: Not the same type as B." << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    double d_;
};


int main () {

  A a;
  B b;

  a.Check (); // should be false
  b.Check (); // should be true

  return 0;
}
```

However this code does not compile. The error I get is:

```
main.cc: In member function ‘void A::Check()’:
main.cc:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B’
main.cc:6: error: forward declaration of ‘struct B’
```

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem you are trying to solve is much better handled by a virtual method:

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual bool Check() { return false; };
}


class B : public A
{
    public:
        // override A::Check()
        virtual bool Check() { return true; };
}
```

Methods in the base class A should not need to know whether the object is "really" an A or a B. That's a violation of basic object-oriented design principles. If the behavior needs to change when the object is a B, then that behavior should be defined in B and handled by virtual method calls.

Comment: It did not occur to me that I was violating basic OOP principles. Not to mention that what I was trying to do did not work.
As you suggested, I rewrote everything using virtual functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just move the definition of Check() out of the body of A:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A {
  public:
    int i_;
    void Check ();
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    double d_;
};

void A::Check () {
  if (typeid (*this) == typeid (B))
    cout << "True: Same type as B." << endl;
  else
    cout << "False: Not the same type as B." << endl;
}

int main () {

  A a;
  B b;

  a.Check (); // should be false
  b.Check (); // should be true

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the quick answer! What you suggested actually worked. However I preferred rewriting everything in terms of virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pull the definition of `Check` out of the class definition, so that `B` is defined when the compiler gets to the function definition.

```
class A {
    //...
    void Check();
    //...
};
class B { /* ... */ };

void A::Check() {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your definition of the Check below your declaration of class B.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the function body after the declaration of B.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A
{
    int i_;
    void Check();
};

struct B :  A
{
    double d_;
};

void A::Check()
{
    using namespace std;
    if (typeid (*this) == typeid (B))
    {
        cout << "True: Same type as B." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "False: Not the same type as B." << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.Check(); // should be false
    b.Check(); // should be true

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Hi,
even if you put the definition of A::Check outside the class the result won't be what you expect. This is because the B object this convert to an A object in the method so this points on a A object thus the typeids are always different. To solve this declare the method virtual.

However, I still don't understand why you want to perform such a test O_o ?? And as CAdaker said this is not good practice

Comment: I'd like to do that in order to trigger different methods, based on the type of class.

    if b.Check() then b.method_in_the_subclass(); else b.method_in_the_superclass();    

But thanks to all your hints I see this hardly can be considered good practice.